# Retrieving the top value or marginTop value of dynamically created elements when clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to find to top of an element when I click on it.  How do I do this?  When I do the following, it returns 0px for each element I click on,

```
$(".schematics").on("click touchstart", function(ev){
    var top = $(this).css("marginTop");
    console.log(top, $(this).height());
    ev.preventDefault();
})
```

When I change it to the following, I get the value of auto,

```
$(".schematics").on("click touchstart", function(ev){
    var top = $(this).css("top");
    console.log(top, $(this).height());
    ev.preventDefault();
})
```

These elements are being appended to a parent div with Javascript, I don't know if that has anything to do with it or not.  If it'll help to add the script that's appending them, let me know and I'll add it.

Comment: Did you try `$(this).offset().top` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this it might work

```
$(this).offset().top
```

Comment: Indeed it does.  Thanks.  I'll accept your answer when I'm able to.